# Jsoup seems to be caching, can I disable this?

Tags: java, caching, jsoup

I'm trying to use `reddit.com/r/subreddit/random` to get a random link from /r/nocontext. However, it seems to bring me to the same link repeatedly should I put this code in a loop. This brings me to think that Jsoup is caching the webpage, but I need to disable this. Here's my code:

```
Document doc = null;
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.reddit.com/r/nocontext/random").get();
    Elements elements = doc.select("div.entry.unvoted p.title a.title");

    for (Element link : elements) 
        System.out.println(link.text());

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Anyone have any insight on how to fix this problem?

Comment: are you sure its jsoup? what happens if you hit it repeatedly in your browser? it seems to be giving me the same url in firefox.  the sessions/caching might be server-side to reddit.

Comment: I tried in chrome, and it didn't happen. It's possible though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most probably cached by the server.
check the [Rules](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API#rules) in their API.

especially I quote this:

> Most pages are cached for 30 seconds, so you won't get fresh data if
>   you request the same page that often. Don't hit the same page more
>   than once per 30 seconds.

so make your request be every 30+ seconds and see if your problem is solved.

Answer (score -2):

GET requests can be cached, where as POST requests can never be cached. Changing your connection request from get() to post() will avoid this.